# Date time implementation based on culture mvc4

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application which I developed in the UK.  I have now deployed this to a US server and the dates are incorrect.  I have a date time picker which I have set the format to be dd/mm/yyyy, when I select the date time picker I notice that when I inspect the element the date is actually 12/10/2013.

When I store this to the database this is being transformed as 2013-12-10 and then when I retrieve this from the database it is actually 10/12/2013.

Also when I call DateTime.Now in the code this is coming back as a US format (mm/dd/yyyy).  I need everything to be consistent. How?

I have tried setting the culture info in the web config `<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />` but this is having no effect, some areas i am storing the date in sql server as GETDATE() and sometimes this is passed in as `DateTime`

Comment: Why are you ever treating ***dates*** as d/m/y or m/d/y formatted ***strings***? They're not strings and should only ever be treated as strings at the very last stage in displaying them to the user. In all other cases, keep them as ***dates*** and then you never have to worry about regional and ambiguous formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually think you're dealing with incorrect behavior, you're most likely dealing with different TEXT representations of the SAME underlying `DateTime` or `DATE` item:

- If Visual Studio is running on a system with `en-US` regional settings, it's insepectors will obviously use those settings when displaying dates in the debugger.
- If you're looking at an `SQL` column with a data type of `DATE`, SQL might use the "SQL" standard representation for string, and that's why you see "2013-12-10"
- When you're using Object Inspector to inspect the `DateTime` value selected into a control, Visual Studio is again using the system's settings to display that date. It can't show you the actual binary representation.

The crust of the problem:

- Make sure you differentiate your actual date (stored in a `DateTime` variable or a `DATE` database column) from it's TEXT representation.
- Make sure you get the correct date.
- Make sure your application's users see the date in the expected format.
- Learn to deal with the text representations of date that only you as a developer would see (the SQL-style representation and the Visual Studio inspector representation).